# Unresolved dependency в build.sbt файле

Tags: scala, sbt

В файле build.sbt хочу добавить библиотеку ScalaMeter. Если на скрине не видно, то вот содержимое файла

```
name := "Parallel"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.0"

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at
  "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

libraryDependencies += "com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter-core" % "0.7"
```

Я сильно в sbt не разбираюсь и делал как [ЗДЕСЬ](https://scalameter.github.io/home/download/)

После добавления последней строки IDEA сразу же подчеркевает содержимое красным и выдает `Unresolved dependency`. После обновления я получаю вот такое:

```
 Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.8 ...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.storm-enroute#scalameter-core_2.12;0.7: not found
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.storm-enroute#scalameter-core_2.12;0.7: not found
[error] Total time: 8 s, completed Dec 2, 2016 12:33:07 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="/home/vovanrew/.IdeaIC2016.2/system/log/sbt.last.log">/home/vovanrew/.IdeaIC2016.2/system/log/sbt.last.log</a>
```

**Подскажите, как как правильно установить эту зависимость и подключить библиотеку?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Для scala 2.12 нет такой версии `scalameter-core` артефакта. Существующие можно глянуть [здесь](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.storm-enroute/scalameter-core_2.12).

Меняй или версию артефакта, или версию скалы.

Comment: Поменял версию скалы на 2.10.0. Та же проблема

Comment: Аналогичный результат со скалой 2.11. Странно, ведь на сайте автора библиотеки написано, что 2.10 и 2.11 подойдут